# Bash cut and remove characters

Tags: bash

Here is the user email for example...

```
mburkhar@imap1.tech.com
```

I want to cut out the `mburkhar` and also remove the `imap.` in the email to look like this in a new file. I have been working on this for a while but there are so many different commands I am confused as to what I should actually be using for this problem.

```
mburkhar mburkhar@tech.com
```

Comment: Are you doing this for lots of different email addresses that look different? Or do they all have imap1 as the start of the domain?

Comment: so I have the first command cutting the username out with `cut -d @ -f1 (filename)` but for the second part there are multiple emails so it might be like `imap1 imap2` or `imap3` so I know i will need a wildcard `?` at the end

Comment: Are you processing a stream of lines (as with an input file) or a single value, already in a shell variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s=mburkhar@imap1.tech.com
s_name=${s%%@*}
s_adjusted=${s//@imap1./@}
echo "Name is $s_name; adjusted email address is $s_adjusted"
```

When run, this will have the output:

> Name is mburkhar; adjusted email address is mburkhar@tech.com

...of course, for your originally requested output, you could

```
echo "$s_name $s_adjusted"
```

...or, to implement this as a one-liner, assuming again your original value in the variable `$s`:

```
echo "${s%%@*} ${s//@imap1./@}"
```

---

These are [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) operations, performed internally to bash, and thus more efficient than using any external process such as sed.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a quick `sed` script:

```
sed 's/\([^@]*\)@imap[0-2]\.\(.*\)$/\1 \1@\2/'
```

Comment: This enables you to do it in the vaunted one-liner style... :-)

Comment: The PE approach is similarly one-liner-capable; I was going for something longer for readability.

Comment: I know - I was just desperate for a comeback... :-)

Comment: I'd say there's a comeback already built-in -- if you're processing a stream of inputs, rather than a single input, this is going to be more graceful. (One can, of course, iterate over a stream in bash and perform PE on each value, but with a large enough input source the performance overhead of starting up `sed` can be overcome by bash's inherent sloth).

Comment: Very gracious of you. On that note I think I've finished my SO'ing for the night. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sed` command to do this:

```
echo "mburkhar@imap1.tech.com" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)@imap[^\.]*.\(.*\)/\1 \1@\2/'
mburkhar mburkhar@tech.com
```

This will capture the part before the `@` ignore any string starting with `imap` just after the `@` and capture the end of the address.

If no `imap` is found the output will be like this:

```
echo "mburkhar@tech.com" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)@imap[^\.]*.\(.*\)/\1 \1@\2/'
mburkhar@tech.com
```

Comment: BTW, since this is tagged bash rather than sh, I'd consider `sed ... <<<"mburkhar@tech.com"` rather than `echo "mburkhan@tech.com" | sed ...`; slightly less overhead.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i don't know <<< until now :) and it's a example to copy paste into a terminal to see the command works (or not).